# Create a view to show users who flagged other users

Tags: 7, views, users, flags

I have created a User flag as Report Abuse. Users may flag other users with this flag. Now i want to create a view where the users who are flagged along with the flagging user are shown. However i am unable to show the flagging user (though i am getting the user id of the flagging user). It should have been quite simple. I have added, i think, the required relationships. Here's a screen shot of the view settings.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it was quite easy actually. I just added a field in User:Name and added the relationship as Flag User as the required relationship